# C# & Java & C++ Message Passing Mechanism

Tags: c#, java, c++, message-passing

What is C# & Java & C++ Message Passing Mechanism ?

Comment: Do you mean how do method calls work, how to pass asynchronous tasks between threads, or queued messages between processes or how best to communicate between C#, Java and C++?

Comment: I can help you provided I know what you need. I have listed everything I can think of.  Can you explain what you do mean?

Comment: I suggest you read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing so you have a better idea what you are asking.  Note: developers rarely refer to "Message Passing" as it can mean any number of things (as I listed above)

Comment: I want know Message-Passing mechanisms in different object oriented languages and what mechanisms are provided from object oriented languages.

Comment: The various ways this can be done is listed on that page.  Is a more specific question that page doesn't answer you would like to know the answer to?

Answer (score 1):

Vague question but have you looked at MSMQ? ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: What is message passing mechanism in object oriented languages such as C++ , C# , Java and How this languages implements message passing in their languages ?